# R - Clear brackets and anything inside it with gsub

Tags: regex, r

Simple question. Suppose I have string like below:

```
Norway(19)
```

I want to remove the `(19)` from the string using `gsub`, what is the proper regex to do so?

This is my code and it removes the brackets but not what's inside of it:

```
s1<-as.character("Norway(19)")
s1<-gsub("\\(|\\)", "", s1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `ca)` if you're using vim :}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s1<-as.character("Norway(19)")
s1<-gsub("\\(.*\\)", "", s1)
```

should get you there, `.` is the wildcard in regex and `*` repeats something 0 or more times.

Comment: Or perhaps `gsub("(.*)\\(.*","\\1",s1)`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
string <- 'Norway(19)'

> gsub( '\\(\\d+)','',string)
[1] "Norway"
```

`\\(` for the first bracket, `\\d+` for the number and just `)` for the closing bracket.